# Symfony 2.8 - Controller listener, get controller after redirect

Tags: symfony

I'm currently try to implement a controller listener which needs to be executed before every action:

```
class AuthenticationListener 
{
/**
 * @var TokenStorage
 */
private $tokenStorage;

/**
 * @var $controller
 *
 * Controller that is accessed
 */
private $controller;

/**
 * @var string $class full class path of controller
 */
private $class;

public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    // Get controller after redirect here?
    $this->controller = $event->getController()[0];
    $this->class = get_class($this->controller);
}

}
```

However, when there is a redirect this listener receives the RedirectController instead of the controller that is targeted by the user. Is there anyway to get the name of controller which comes after the redirect?

Comment: You could use the FilterControllerArgumentsEvent to get the name of the route being redirected to.  But get the actual controller would be a bit more challenging.

Comment: That is not desirable since it would create implicit coupling between the routes in routing.yml and the listener. Change of path in url would require to alter it at two places

Comment: Okay so why are you trying to get the redirected controller?  After all, eventually the redirect will happen and you will get the controller then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is possible, normally you can call `Request::getParameter('_controller')` and you should get the original controller.